# R shiny graph does not change when drop down selection is made

Tags: r, input, ggplot2, shiny, reactive

Nothing changes in the graph once a selection is made from the selectInput drop down menu- does not look like input form the drop down in being used or not sure the activeSwitch(activeOnSwitch) is working, TIA:

global.R

```
today = format(Sys.time(), "%m%d%Y")
MovingAverageNumber = 12
StartNumber = 1

as.Date_origin <- function(x){
  as.Date(x, origin = min(index))
}

# Load Datahead()
ValuationData <- read.csv("N:/DATA/GFI/GLOBAL RQA/MAPS/Global All/Working Folders/2017/March/Bbg World Sector Valuation v2.csv", header=T,row.names=1,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                      na.strings = c("N/A", "#N/A", "NA", "Null", ""))

index <- as.Date(rownames(ValuationData), format = "%m / %d / %Y")
ValuationData['dt'] = index
origin <- min(index)
labels <- index

legendlabels = c(labels[MovingAverageNumber+1],labels[seq.int(1L, length(index), 12L)],labels[length(index)])


    ma <- function(arr, n=MovingAverageNumber){
res = arr
for(i in n:length(arr)){
res[i] = mean(arr[(i-n+1):i])
}
res
}
```

server.R

```
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("scales", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("shiny", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("packrat", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("zoo", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 

activeSwitch <- function(x) {switch(x,Active=1,Absolute=0)}
activeOnSwitch <- input$ActiveOrAbsolute
Active <- ma(ValuationData[,StartNumber]) - ma(ValuationData[,1])*(activeSwitch(activeOnSwitch))
#Active <- ma(ValuationData[,StartNumber]) - ma(ValuationData[,1])*(0)
ActiveChange <- Active[1:length(Active)-1] - Active[2:length(Active)]


ggplot(ValuationData[MovingAverageNumber+1:length(index),],aes(
  Active[MovingAverageNumber+1:length(index)], 
  ActiveChange[MovingAverageNumber+1:length(index)-1],
  colour=as.integer(dt))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_color_gradientn(name = "Dates",
                        colours = rainbow(7), 
                        breaks = as.integer(legendlabels), 
                        labels = format(legendlabels, "%b-%y")) +
  geom_path(size=3) +
  xlab("12 Month Average P/E Fwd 12 Month") +ylab("12 Month Average Monthly Change in P/E Fwd 12 Month") +
  ggtitle( paste(colnames(ValuationData)[StartNumber], Title)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey80"))

  })
})
```

ui.R

```
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("scales", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("shiny", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("packrat", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")
library("zoo", lib.loc="H:/My Documents/R/R-3.2.1/library")




shinyUI(fluidPage(


  # Application title
  titlePanel("Valuation Cycles"),

  sidebarLayout(

    selectInput("ActiveOrAbsolute", "Active Or Absolute:",
            c("Active" = 1,
              "Absolute" = 0 )),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: [How to make a great _minimal_ and _reproducible_ example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?

Comment: > head(Active)
[1] 15.2928 15.5196 15.8208 15.5736 14.9574 14.8441

Comment: Including the first 6 values of `Active` doesn't allow us to run your code.  We need an example of "ValuationData".  See the link given above for ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Managed to solve with this adding within shiny server and render, cut out some for brevity:   

shinyServer(... {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ 
    
    SectorNumber <- as.numeric(input$Sector)
    Active <- ma(ValuationData[,SectorNumber]) - ma(ValuationData[,1])*( activeOnSwitch )
    ActiveChange <- Active[2:length(Active)] - Active[1:length(Active)-1] 
    ActiveDF <- data.frame(cbind(Active[2:length(Active)],ActiveChange,ValuationData[2:length(Active),'dt']))
    names(ActiveDF) <- c("Active", "ActiveChange", "dates")
    ggplot(...+
...